# Adding multiple database values in one PHP value

Tags: php, mysql

If I have the following table in my database:

Students:

```
**Student  Grade  Gender**
Joey       5    male
Patrick    8    male
Matt       3    male
Ann        6    female
Mary       9    female
```

By using PHP/MySQL, what is the best way to get all the grades of all the male students and add them all in a PHP variable? So in this case I want a variable with the value of 16.

Comment: depends how you want them in the arraylist, as an object or just an arraylist?

Comment: As a starter for you: `select sum(Grade) from Students where Gender='male'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply select them with sql query and a bit of PHP for you:

```
$SQL = 'select sum(Grade) from Students where Gender="male"';

$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["connection"], $SQL) or die("Couldn't execute query: ".mysqli_error($GLOBALS["connection"]));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $Total_grade = $row['Grade']; // assigning result to $Total_grade PHP variable
}
```

you would need to look into `mysqli_query` procedures or `MySQLi` object

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same problem, this was my final code. The above code did not entirely work for me.

```
$SQL = 'select sum(Grade) as total from Students';
$Total_grade = 0;
$result = mysqli_query($link, $SQL);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $Total_grade = $row['total'];
}
```